# How can I convert a protocol buffers message to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, protocol-buffers

Here's my use case.

I work on a multi language system that communicates over protobuf and zeromq between several different languages, one of which is C#.

I want to implement a WCF JSON web service over our database and I want to use protocol buffers to ensure the correct json schema. The WCF web service works fine now and I could easily create standard `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` marked up classes with the same schema as my protobuf class, but I'd really like to have this automatic.

Here's roughly what I've got:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<ProtoBufClass> MyData();
}

public partial class Service : IMyService
{

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               UriTemplate = "")]
    public IEnumerable<ProtoBufClass> MyData()
    {
        return from nd someLinqQuery
               // I want: select new ProtoBufClass.CreateBuilder()
               //                      .SetA(nd.A).SetB(nd.B).SetC(nd.C).Build()
               // This is what I have now
               select new ProtoBufClass(nd.A, nd.B, nd.C)
    }
}
```

At the moment `ProtoBufClass` is manually written with the afore mentioned `[Data*]` attributes and therefore has no guarantee of correctness when I try and use it in other parts of the system. What I want is for ProtoBufClass to be the actual generated class which is common across all of our languages and for is to automatically be serialized to JSON for me.

It would be extra cool if I could do:

```
http://host/Service
  => protobuf message as json
http://host/Service <{Content-Type: protobuf}> | ?format=protobuf
  => serialized protobuf message
```

Any pointers on how to expose this service over a zeromq socket would also be much appreciated, I've implemented protobuf RPC with python but I've got no idea how to do it in C#

Thanks
Ben

*edit* I forgot to mention that I'm using protobuf-csharp-port as opposed to protobuf-net

Comment: I did see the last line, but just to state: in the case of protobuf-net, because it can work with arbitrary POCO, it makes it pretty easy to work with multiple serializers. Doesn't sound like that will help you - but it might help some other random reader in the future.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the comment. So are you saying that if I was using protobuf-net i'd just be able to return an instance of a protobuf class and the DataContract serialization would just work?

Comment: sure; as long as the model has numeric keys one way or another